# Getting anonymous object in java 8 as we do in C# linq

Tags: c#, lambda, java-8

Let's suppose I have a Person class having fields like FirstName, LastName, Age, Salary etc. Now I've this code in C# linq, where persons is a List.

```
var lstFirstAndLastNamesOnly = persons.Where(x => x.Age > 35).Select(x => new {x.FirstName, x.LastName}).ToList();
```

This is going to get me an anonymous type having FirstName and LastName. How do I write something like this in Java 8? What could be the better ways so as only a handful of fields are returned when I have say 100 fields on the class.

Comment: There simply aren't anonymous types in Java in the same way as in C#. (Yes, you can have anonymous classes, but they're not really the same in any meaningful way, and would be very ugly to use in Java 8 streams.)

Comment: Java is strictly staticly typed, there is no such thing as an "anonoymous type".

Comment: @dabadaba C# anonymous types are not dynamic -- they are fully part of a statically typed ecosystem. (their semantics are enforced at compile-time)

Comment: @Jon Skeet. Thank you Jon. I've realized it's the community(in java) that's so welcoming, it's winning me now. Getting a reply in minutes in awesome.  I'm just starting to learn java, I'll speed it up now. Thanks again.

Comment: @dabadaba: As Kirk says, anonymous types in C# are still statically typed, and Java *does* have anonymous classes - they're just rather different. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5

Comment: there are other languages targeting the JVM though. E.g. scala has tuple types.

Answer (score 11):

Well, the Java programming language has anonymous types, but they aren’t as useful as in that C# example. I.e., the following would work:

```
persons.stream().filter(x -> x.age > 35)
    .map(x -> new Object(){ String first = x.firstName, last = x.lastName; })
    .forEach(name -> System.out.println(name.first + " " + name.last));
```

As you will notice, the declaration of an anonymous type still requires a type specification, which will be the supertype of the anonymous type. Further, you have to formally declare the members holding the data with type and name.

Prior to JDK 10, lambda expressions were the only place where you can declare a variable (the parameters) without specifying their type and letting the compiler infer it.

Starting with JDK 10, you can use the `var` keyword to declare a local variable whose type is inferred from its initializer, even if it is a non-denotable type.

```java
var name = persons.stream().filter(x -> x.age > 35)
    .map(x -> new Object(){ String first = x.firstName, last = x.lastName; })
    .orElse(null);
if(name != null) System.out.println(name.first + " " + name.last);
```

You may access it in a fluent context, without a variable, which also works in versions prior to JDK 10, like

```
System.out.println(
    persons.stream().filter(x -> x.age > 35)
        .map(x -> new Object(){ String a = x.firstName, b = x.lastName; })
        .findFirst().get().a
);
```

but since this only allows accessing a single member, it’s of little use, as, if you only need a single member, you could just `map` to the member value in the first place.

In this specific example, you could use a two element `String` array instead:

```
List<String[]> lstFirstAndLastNamesOnly = persons.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.age > 35)
    .map(x -> new String[] { x.firstName, x.lastName })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
lstFirstAndLastNamesOnly
    .forEach(name -> System.out.println(name[0]+" "+name[1]));
```

but, of course, they are no replacement for real tuples, especially when you have heterogeneously typed elements.

---

It should be noted that such an anonymous type still is a distinct type, i.e. another anonymous type created at a different code location having identical properties still is a different type. In fact, even instances with the same property values are not equal, as long as you don’t add an appropriate `equals` method.

Starting with JDK 16, you can use a `record` for this purpose. It’s not an anonymous class, but the best tool for the purpose of creating an ad-hoc type containing some properties. It’s still a distinct type, but it can be declared locally¹ and automatically gets useful `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString` implementations.

```java
var listFirstAndLastNamesOnly = persons.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.age > 35)
    .map(x -> {
        record Name(String firstName, String lastName) {}
        return new Name(x.firstName, x.lastName);
    })
    .toList();

// utilize generated toString() method
listFirstAndLastNamesOnly.forEach(System.out::println);

// or
listFirstAndLastNamesOnly
    .forEach(name -> System.out.println(name.firstName()+" "+name.lastName()));
```

Note that this again utilizes `var` for the variable declaration because the `Name` record declared inside the mapping function is not in scope. Likewise, the lambda expression passed to `forEach` infers the right element type. Since this relies on a feature of local variables, it only works when the entire code is within one method.

¹ even better than anonymous classes as the `record` won’t capture a `this` reference from the surrounding context

Comment: It works if you are immediately using the anonymous type for printing or any other purpose in `forEach()`. Otherwise, an Object is returned and since Java does not have a `var` type facility to automatically deduce the type, we have to take it as `Stream<Object>`. Now we can't access the members anymore.

Comment: @Jagannath: that’s exactly what this answer says.